# Bell Curved Grading

Tags: grading

I have two questions:

- How can I know which university/school uses Bell Curved Grading system,and which one doesn't?
- Suppose, I have two acceptances from two schools *(a)* one applies Curved grading, and *(b)* another one doesn't. Is there any reason I should choose the one without curve so that I can be on the safe side?

Comment: (i) You can ask them? (ii) That depends on how the other school grades and on your personal goals and abilities.

Comment: (i) most are online, disclaimer: https://www.fastweb.com/student-life/articles/what-to-know-about-professor-rating-websites (ii) I think your metric is REALLY THE WRONG one. At university level, grades are not absolute. They are important, but only in the context of the school. The quality of learning and reputation of the school are as and more important. The networking starts being important too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is simply no way to know, because there are no uniform grading standards within universities. I know that I do not enforce bell-curve grading, and neither do many of my colleagues, while others do.

Also, many universities do not recommend bell curve grading, because it makes grading more challenging, because technically you’d have to change lots of grades if you make a grading mistake. Instead, they recommend choosing one “fixed grade”—for instance, the mark between passing and failing—and the increment to the next level.

Answer (score 6):

**All universities use bell curves to some extent.**

- Sometimes they are very clear about this, stating in the syllabus: "the top 15% of students will get an A", etc.
- Others claim not to curve: "if you get a 90%, you get an A. I'll give an A to everyone in the class if everyone gets a 90%." But in practice, the difficulty of the exercises/exams reacts to the students' performance, so as to reverse-engineer the desired bell curve.

So, I would argue that this is a  false distinction.

That said:

- **Some universities may have guidelines or culture that encourages one or the other.** As noted in the comments, the only real way to find out is to ask them (though they may be confused by the question)
- **Things will vary even within a university.** In my experience, some graduate programs will give an A to everyone who completes the course, while some intro-level science courses in the same university have a bell curve such that the average grade is a C. Decisions about how to grade generally lie with the instructor.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's a false disctinction. The fundamental difference in the second approach is that the grades of an individual student do not depend on the performance of her fellow students. The first approach is more conducive to a competitive, and potentially hostile, environment.

Comment: The second approach may "trick" some students into being less hostile (which is maybe a good thing!). But even in this case, if everyone else is doing well, the final will be harder, and I will do worse. The only way around this is if the instructor pre-sets the assessment items and grading scheme at the beginning of the course and then doesn't change them -- but this is very rare; most instructors haven't taught the course often enough to know what is fair, and so rely on students' performance to adjust the difficulty level.